# Android / Fragment inside of List View

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, layout-inflater, fragmenttransaction

I am trying to create a list view of fragments, which normally should show delivery address fragment, but should change fragment if user clicks the edit button, then it should show the edit delivery address fragment.

I am making use of `fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.deliveryaddress, showAddress);` with custom list view adapter to show fragment inside list view. The above statement works well when setContentView is used inside an onCreate function for an activity and when layout is inflated inside an OnCreateView function for a Fragment, but what to do if a layout is inflated inside a getView function for an array adapter? The above statement does not work out well at all then. It returns with the following error message of:

```
E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f080064 (com.melorra.nativeapp:id/deliveryaddress) for fragment ShowAddress{7b0a85a #3 id=0x7f080064}
```

Please help me out to fix this error up.

Profile.java

```
...
AddressAdapter addressAdapter = new AddressAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.fragment, addressList, getFragmentManager());
...
```

AddressAdapter.java

```
public class AddressAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DeliveryAddress> {
    Context con;
    int _resource;
    List<DeliveryAddress> lival;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public AddressAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<DeliveryAddress> li, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(context, resource, li);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        con = context;
        _resource = resource;
        lival = li;
        fragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup vg) {
        View vi = null;
        LayoutInflater linflate = (LayoutInflater) con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = linflate.inflate(_resource, null);

        DeliveryAddress deliveryAddress = lival.get(position);

        ShowAddress showAddress = new ShowAddress(deliveryAddress);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = fragmentManager;
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = fragmentManager1.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.deliveryaddress, showAddress);
        fragmentTransaction1.commit();

        return vi;
    }
}
```

profile.xml

```
...
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/addresslist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
...
```

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/deliveryaddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You cannot have a listview of fragments. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Seriously? And why? In a list view, I am trying to display list of user's delivery addresses, and each of them which should load another fragment inside corresponding list item to that whenever that user clicks on edit button. If it is not possible, can you suggest some other alternative for it?

Comment: Is it at least possible to make use of fragment inside of a recycler view, if not for list view and grid view at the very least?

Comment: It sounds like you could use a [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView). However it would not be fragments within the list, it would be a new view that expands when you click on an item. You could also create a new fragment when you click on a list item, navigating the user to a new screen. But as I said, a list of Fragments is not possible. A list of Views are possible.